# Add mail to user register with user_external_login_register

Tags: users

I'm creating a module that should add an external authentication server, and I'm using [user_external_login_register](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7) function.

The problem is that the user created with this functions does not have a "mail" attribute, and also if I try to user_load it, the mail attribute is not present.
Why?

Is there a way to add it or I've to create user in the ordinary way, by code?

I could add it on hook_user_insert, but the mail address is a response from a web services, called before the hook.

Answer (score 0):

The function user_save is called in user_external_login_register, so you could just use hook_user_insert to add the info you need.

Comment: I know it. The problem is that, if I have a function where I call the user_external_login_register, there I've the call to the web services. If I want to pass data go hook_user_insert I should pass variables in session, or cache, or not?

Comment: After calling user_external_login_register the global $user should contain the user object. Check if it has the mail property and update if needed.

Comment: No, the user object hasn't the mail attribute, also if I try user_load